# Python-Creating an array from a .csv file and getting the sum of that array

Tags: python, arrays, file, csv

I have a csv file that has numbers in it that I have entered from another python program.  My goal is take these numbers and get the sum of these numbers in python.  My first thought would be to pull the numbers from the file and create an array.  Then sum the array.  I can pull the numbers and print them, but I can't sum them up using sum(array).

The csv file is straightforward like this:

```
    100
    40
    50
```

I tried this:

```
    array=[]

    with open('testScores.csv') as fileName:
        for line in fileName:
            array.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

    total=sum(array)

    print(total)
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "G:\test1.py", line 14, in <module>
    total=sum(array)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I'm not very familiar with this and I'm unsure how to proceed.

I will ultimately take this sum and divide it by the number of lines in the CSV file to get an average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your error is that there is no `tostring` method for the list `array`. Instead, what I think you want to do is push an integer value onto the end of `array` so that you can `sum` the `array` later on.

Assuming that each line contains only one integer value, you can use this:

```
array.append(int(line))
```

in place of the 4th line in your code.

Comment: No need for the `rstrip`, actually: both `int` and `float` ignore leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.  This is my first question so i had the formatting wrong.

Comment: @FreddieB1027: converting the lines to `int` as shown in my code should solve the TypeError you're getting, too.

Comment: When I make the adjustment to that line I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\test1.py", line 13, in <module>
    array.append(int(line.rstrip('\n')))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100.0'

Comment: @FreddieB1027: so use `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: @DSM.  Awesome.  That took care of that and got me my sum.  Glad to know I wasn't too terribly off in my thinking.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have numpy installed, you can do

`print sum( numpy.loadtxt( 'testScores.csv' ) )`

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: I don't have numpy installed.  Sorry.  I'm really not familiar with it.